# how can i select something from google forms drop down menu with python selenium there is only divs no select tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, google-forms

this is the form link: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe61r6TNx4JvRg2gVu3Eu8-KYKCvd1dJCAmYJFnNw4EU9llMw/viewform this is my code i want to select DHAOUI MOHAMED AZIZ what am i missing  :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def sleep():
    time.sleep(5)

Chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/dhaou/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe61r6TNx4JvRg2gVu3Eu8-KYKCvd1dJCAmYJFnNw4EU9llMw/viewform"
Chrome.get(url)
first_div = Chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div')
first_div.click()
sleep()
second=Chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[16]')
second.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me for the url you had provided.

```
PATH = "./chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe61r6TNx4JvRg2gVu3Eu8-KYKCvd1dJCAmYJFnNw4EU9llMw/viewform"
driver.get(url)

element = ".quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption.appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption.freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled.exportOption.isSelected.isPlaceholder"

dropdown = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(element)
dropdown.click()

name = "ALI GHANMI"
list_element = "//div[@class='exportSelectPopup quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectPopup']//span[text()='"+name+"']"

dropdown_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(list_element)
dropdown_element.click()
```

By the way, The form in the URL you had provided does not have `DHAOUI MOHAMED AZIZ`. I tried a different name.